# Pandas DataFrame to SQL synthax

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe structured in this way:

```
     username   last login
0    james.js   2018-06-20
1    rachel.wm  2018-06-20
4    john.a     2018-06-20
5    andrew.rs  2018-06-20
```

and I would like to format it in a way that I can execute a query like this one:

```
INSERT INTO schema.login
(username, last_login)
VALUES 
(james.js,  2018-06-20),
(rachel.wm, 2018-06-20),
(john.a,    2018-06-20),
(andrew.rs, 2018-06-20);
```

how can I format this dataframe in that way?

Comment: Did you try `pandas.DataFrame.to_sql`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html?

Comment: I can't create an engine and user pandas to execute the query, I just want to format the dataframe

Comment: So are you saying you just want to create a string to represent the whole sql statement?

Comment: Yes, in a way that this string, if run, will work